# Filtering my batches (no dead fishes)

Tags: equipment, filtering, finings, fining

I have had a couple of cloudy batches recently, both tasted as intended, so no contamination. This has caused me to consider filtration, I have a 100l kit with a pump so could use plate filters or membrane filters etc, as I should have enough power to cope with the pressure drop across the filter.

I have also considered using finings, but do not want to add any isinglass to my beers as I have many vegan and vegetarian friends whom enjoy drinking them.

My questions are these:

1) What filtering options should I consider?

2) What fining options should I use other than isinglass?

3) How do finings and filtering work in conjunction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I've not used plate filters but seems they would work well, but be expensive. I use a cartridge water filter, and find they are easily cleanable and reusable a few times.
[image]

2) Try Clairty Ferm, is enzyme based and it can actually drop gluten to FDA "gluten free" levels.
https://www.whitelabs.com/other-products/wln4000-clarity-ferm-brewers-clarex
If you want an inorganic you're left using silica gel or PVPP.

3) If you use a clairifier there shouldn't be the need to filter. Also filters do little to remove chill haze, while clairifiers can help.

Comment: What cartridge filter do you use?

Comment: @Mr_road updated with pic

Comment: How large of batches do you filter with your cartridge?  I've thought about using mine for clearing beer quickly but I don't want to lose the beer in the body of the filter.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I filter from corney to corney using co2, so 5gal.

Comment: Do you find that gets all the beer though the filter or does it stay partially full?

Comment: @MatthewWhited I invert the filter at the end, and only lose about 4 fluid ounces.

Answer (score 1):

I just cold age my beers in kegs so they drop clear in about a week.  I can then jump the beer to another keg or bottle after dropping clear to not have to worry about shaking a keg and then having to let all that stuff settle out again.

I have used bentonite in mead and wine.  It worked really well.  (it is a volcanic clay so not animal based.)

I've heard good things about biofine clean (vegan/plant based) but I have not used it yet.  I have used isinglass in wine and it worked really well but that would be the entire fish guts you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Irish moss or carageen moss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chondrus_crispus) (a type of seaweed) is used as a fining agent in commercial brewing.

I'm afraid I can't comment on filtration.